# What are the security issues relating to macro enabled MS office documents?

Tags: virus, office

Are there any security issues relating to macro enabled MS office documents?

Answer (score 3):

There have been several macro viruses in the past where they install macros on any document one opens, though it's been a while since I've seen this attack in use. This kind of malware even rates it's own [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macro_virus).